# Python iframe content with dropdownlist selection

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am looking to extract info for this page : http://www.basketbasko.com/cas/competiciones.asp

I want to extract all the info that was in the different seasons (temporada) dropdownlist, and for some categories (categoría) dropdownlist. In fact I have to extract all the info playing with the for dropdownlist.

I understand that the Dropdownlist value are getting for lines as:

```
<select name="gruposDropDownList" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'gruposDropDownList\',\'\')', 0)" language="javascript" id="gruposDropDownList" class="ControlSeleccion">
    <option selected="selected" value="62399">CLASIFICACION UNICO</option>
    <option value="56679">REGULAR UNICO</option>

</select>
```

How can I search the different iframes that content the info that result of different dropdownlist combination?

Are any python library or manual that I can follow to extract this info.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your code trial please?

Comment: At this moment I have not a code . I don't know how I can access to the different asp or html pages